# Dimension too large/Arithmetic overflow with three (very simple) strands

Tags: errors, tikz-knots

I'm trying to draw a very simple braid diagram, and the below code "half successfully" builds a PDF with the desired output (but only just before the compilation stops from the below error), but I can't use this code in any actual document since it always terminates with `Dimension too large` and `Arithmetic overflow` errors at `\end{knot}`. Deleting one or two of the strands seems to make it compile fine (it depends which ones, it seems like).

1. Why does this error happen?
2. How can I fix it? (Really preferably using the `knots` package).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (1,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (1.5,0) {$\bullet$};
    \begin{knot}
      \strand (1,0) to (0,-3);
      \strand (1.5,0) to (0.5,-3);
      \strand (0,0) to (1.5,-3);
    \end{knot}
    \node at (0,-3) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (0.5,-3) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (1.5,-3) {$\bullet$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because this MWE works, the problem must be somewhere else in the interaction of this code with some of the other code. Without knowing the other code it is not really possible to tell what the problem is. Could you try to create a document that is still small but that shows the actual error (always) when compiled? Also add which compiler you use (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex) and which version of the compiler and the packages, that might be relevant.

Comment: sorry, this code still gives an error, but the partially-complied pdf can still be viewed, but the compilation still stops from the error

Comment: For me the code as posted runs without errors in all three compilers.

Comment: See if your distribuition of LaTeX is outdatad or no. Your code compile fine also for me.

Comment: that is really odd. I've also been trying with LaTeXiT, and it gives me exactly the same errors (and produces no output because of this). I'm using TinyTeX which provides the 2020 version of TeX Live...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an issue with the `intersections` library in PGF.  The `knots` library uses the PGF intersection routines to look for intersections between all of the specified strands (after all, why reinvent the wheel?).  Unfortunately, there is a problem when the PGF library looks for intersections between parallel lines.

I can replicate the issue with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/561184/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, orange,name path=a] (1,0) to (0,-3);
\draw[ultra thick, orange,name path=b] (1.5,0) to (0.5,-3);
\path[name intersections={of=a and b}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(And, for the record, I'm testing this against the very latest development version of PGF.)

What is happening is that when PGF looks for the intersection between two line segments then it tries to be smart and to use a formula rather than actually looking for the intersection (in the way that it does for curves).  Now in the library, there is the following comment:

> In principle, this routine is capable of computing the entire intersection... but we only invoke it after checking for bounding box overlaps. This has two reasons:
>
> 1. robustness. almost-parallel lines could cause "dimension too large" when solving the linear equation system
>    XXX : I still needed to replace the linear solver by one using the FPU. Perhaps I do not need the BB check anymore?
> 2. performance. I hope it is faster to first check for BB (but this is not sure in TeX)

and there are various comments in the code that suggest that the formula being used is being used carefully to check for parallel lines first.

However, clearly something is still going wrong as I get the `dimension too large` with your (parallel) lines.

Obviously, the best outcome would be to fix this in the code.  In the meantime, there are a couple of possible "surface" fixes.  One is to adjust the paths so that they are no longer parallel.  I no longer get the error with:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/561184/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, orange,name path=a] (1,0) to (0.01,-3); % This used to be (0,-3)
\draw[ultra thick, orange,name path=b] (1.5,0) to (0.5,-3);
\path[name intersections={of=a and b}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The other is to force PGF to use the more laborious divide-and-conquer method that it uses for curves.  One way to do this is to put controls at the endpoints:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/561184/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, orange,name path=a] (1,0) .. controls +(0,0) and +(0,0) .. (0,-3);
\draw[ultra thick, orange,name path=b] (1.5,0) to (0.5,-3);
\path[name intersections={of=a and b}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(I don't know if there's an easy way to do this with `to` paths.  One could probably define a `to` path that was a straight-line-but-actually-bézier if one was committed to everything being a `to` path.)

(I need to do a bit of investigating to check that I'm genuinely using the latest code since https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/369 suggests that this has been fixed.  Ah, no, a fix has been *proposed* but not put in place.)

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer to my question, but the following code works fine for me (with no errors) (thanks to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ting__ss/status/1301331842813968385)). I can use this to get the diagram I want, but I still have no idea what's causing the error in the first place, and would like to know...

---

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[knot gap=7]
  \draw[knot] (1,0) to (0,-3);
  \draw[knot] (1.5,0) to (0.5,-3);
  \draw[knot] (0,0) to (1.5,-3);
  \node at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (1,0) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (1.5,0) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (0,-3) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (0.5,-3) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (1.5,-3) {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```